# How to autowire a list of properties with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Java:

```
@Value("${my.list}")
private List<String> list;
```

`application.properties`:

```
my.list=one,two,three
```

How can I autowire all values separated into the `List` using `@Value` with Spring? Is there any chance this is supported?

Comment: Have you tried it ? If so, what's the error or what's the observed misbehavior ?

Comment: I have tried it and the list contains a single entry `[one,two,three]`. I would assume it shoudl contain three entries.

Comment: See if the last answer in the linked duplicate is good enough for you, assuming you don't want to use XML.

Comment: OK spel expression works as expected!

Comment: String[] strings = list.split(",");  List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(strings);